# Convert WebM to Opus without encoding?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, windows-media-player, webm, opus

Tried all various commands with **ffmpeg** and also tried using **mkvconvert** and while they both instantly convert or extract the ***.opus*** from the ***.webm*** file.. the problem is the output file is always slightly smaller in size, instead of being the exact same... and as a result when I try to open the files with Windows Media Player I get an error message:

---

**Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file.**

---

[Screenshot - size comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCkmD.jpg) `ffmpeg -i "%%~na.webm" -c:a copy "%%~na.opus"`

The only way I've found to correctly convert the files manually is simply open each of the WebM files in Notepad++ and then Save as .opus. And it works perfectly. But I want to be able to do the same thing automatically with ffmpeg.

Already searched for like a few hours, and tried lots of commands, but nothing worked.

Also tried `mkvextract "%%~na.webm" tracks 0:"%%~na.opus""` which has the same error problem.
[Screenshot - file comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6cV7.jpg)

Comment: If renaming is all that it takes, why not just batch-rename the files?

Comment: didn't even cross my mind! Just tried `ren "%%~na.webm" "%%~na.opus"` and it perfectly works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ren "%%~na.webm" "%%~na.opus"` works perfectly.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Renaming the file doesn't change the format. It may satisfy WMP, but a genuine `.opus` file doesn't contain any of the metadata structures present in a WebM file nor can it contain video or other data streams. Other players expecting a genuine opus file will fail.

Comment: Yeah no problem, I can any time convert them to opus using ffmpeg if I need to.